# Reverse for 'account_email_verification_sent' not found. 'account_email_verification_sent' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I'm trying to use allauth and rest-auth in my project and try to use the built-in function in allauth to do email verification but this what I get :

[image: Link to screenshot of what I get]

and here is my code

settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
re_path(r'^', include('rest_auth.urls')),
re_path(r'^registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Have you read http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=account_confirm_email?

Comment: Sorry, see https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/292#issuecomment-355099829 and related.

Comment: the named url "account_email_verification_sent" isn't included in either of [`rest_auth.urls`](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/v0.9.3/rest_auth/urls.py) and [`rest_auth.registration.urls`](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/v0.9.3/rest_auth/registration/urls.py).

Comment: You want to include `django_allauth`  [`account.urls`](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/urls.py)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found the solution, I have to add a URL to be able to make a post request to the backend to send an email, with the URL with regex which has the token that will verify the account and URLs, and add a URL for login with name account_login and URL for register with name account_signup and be like this :

```
from rest_auth.registration.views import VerifyEmailView, RegisterView


urlpatterns = [
path('', include('rest_auth.urls')),
path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='account_login'),
path('registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
path('registration/', RegisterView.as_view(), name='account_signup'),
re_path(r'^account-confirm-email/', VerifyEmailView.as_view(),
     name='account_email_verification_sent'),
re_path(r'^account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$', VerifyEmailView.as_view(),
     name='account_confirm_email'),

]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I already had set up the URL for the email confirmation but I forgot about the name parameter it is mandatory

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from dj_rest_auth.registration.views import VerifyEmailView

urlpatterns = [
    url('auth/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')),
    url('auth/registration/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    url('auth/account-confirm-email/', VerifyEmailView.as_view(), name='account_email_verification_sent'),    
]
´´´
```