# verifying users email using django rest auth without errors

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I am creating a rest API and using Django-rest-auth to verify and create users. 
Everything works until I click the link to verify the user's email, but I get an error instead

error message upon following the link to verify the email

```
NoReverseMatch at /account-confirm-email/MjI:1iNmbO:BWhf4WhFzVR99YVYUqCB6X2CbcE/
Reverse for 'account_email' not found. 'account_email' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'users',
]


ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 1
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_LIMIT = 5
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_TIMEOUT = 86400 # 1 day in seconds
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL ='/accounts/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/profile'
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'test@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'test'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'test@gmail.com'
DEFAULT_TO_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER

EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

urls.py

```
from rest_auth.registration.views import VerifyEmailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('api/rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    url('api/rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    re_path(r'^account-confirm-email/$', VerifyEmailView.as_view(), name='account_email_verification_sent'),
    re_path(r'^account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$', VerifyEmailView.as_view(), name='account_confirm_email'),
]
```

A quick fix I made which solved the error a BIT but made it NOT a Rest API was adding a bunch of URLs as shown below

```
    from allauth.account import views

    url(r"^email/$", views.email, name="account_email"),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),

    url(r"^signup/$", views.signup, name="account_signup"),
    url(r"^login/$", views.login, name="account_login"),
    url(r"^logout/$", views.logout, name="account_logout"),

    url(r"^password/change/$", views.password_change,
        name="account_change_password"),
    url(r"^password/set/$", views.password_set, name="account_set_password"),

    url(r"^inactive/$", views.account_inactive, name="account_inactive"),

    # E-mail
    url(r"^email/$", views.email, name="account_email"),
    url(r"^confirm-email/$", views.email_verification_sent,
        name="account_email_verification_sent"),
    url(r"^confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$", views.confirm_email,
        name="account_confirm_email"),

    # password reset
    url(r"^password/reset/$", views.password_reset,
        name="account_reset_password"),
    url(r"^password/reset/done/$", views.password_reset_done,
        name="account_reset_password_done"),
    url(r"^password/reset/key/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<key>.+)/$",
        views.password_reset_from_key,
        name="account_reset_password_from_key"),
    url(r"^password/reset/key/done/$", views.password_reset_from_key_done,
        name="account_reset_password_from_key_done"),
```

as the above didn't fully solve the problem, please how can the account be verified without errors and still maintain being a rest API?

Comment: Why is it looking for `account_email` instead of `account_confirm_email`? I’m talking about the first set of urls, not the fix. Seems like something is looking for `account_email`. Is there a template being called here? Does the email get confirmed?

Comment: the email doesn't get confirmed, when the error shows. I doubt it is supposed to search for a template.

Comment: It's not about doubt, the error indicates it's looking a particular view that presumably doesn't exist, something in the chain is trying to call it and can't find it.

Comment: with a lot of searching I found something, on this link

Comment: https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to this issue a few months back and had a bit of a challenge tracking the issue down.

The `allauth.account` app creates (or should create) two tables in your database: `account_emailaddress` and `account_emailconfirmation`. The reverse lookup is looking for an entry in these tables to verify the email address and then set the account to verified. I found out that during migration, these two tables were not created correctly. I'm not certain why that issue arose (to be honest, I'm still a little new at this stuff).

I had to comment out the `allauth.account` app, run a migration, then reinstate the app and run another migration. That solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this issue.

in users.views I have a view like this

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view()
def null_view(request):
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

then import the null view in urls

```
path('rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/', null_view, name='account_confirm_email'),
```

Comment: thank you very much, this has been troubling me for a while. I will try it out and give feedback on the result, and mark it eventually.

Answer (score 0):

This is Michele from Udemy.

I checked your question and it seems somebody had the same problem and found a solution, here: [Reverse for 'account_email_verification_sent' not found. 'account_email_verification_sent' is not a valid view function or pattern name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48390749/reverse-for-account-email-verification-sent-not-found-account-email-verifica)

Specifically, the problem should be in the way the urls.py file has been handled: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48487631/10221214

I see that you have already done some work on your urls.py file (well done) but maybe instead of having to add so many url paths that can cause troubles (for example, you have two paths with name="account_email" which is wrong!) you can try by copying the ones that have been added in the other question I linked.

One more thing that you could do is to check the repository of the package you are using on GitHub, and from there just look for the error message you get and read the related code.

Please keep me updated!

Michele